# Is it possible to sort a contents of project window manually? (non alphabetically)

Tags: appcode

I want to decide a order of window of project navigator's contents manually.

How to do this?

I attach a image file. Please open it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Currently it is not supported.](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-3919#comment=27-328946)

All you can do is vote for [OC-1666 Project tree: items sorting by type doesn't work](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-1666), and hope JetBrains implements this feature.